# Numpy: transpose result of advanced indexing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, memory-layout

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> x = [0, 1]
>>> X[x, x, :]
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

I need to sum it along the `0` dimension but in the real world the matrix is huge and I would prefer to be summing it along `-1` dimension which is faster due to memory layout. Hence I would like the result to be transposed:

```
array([[ 0, 12],
       [ 1, 13],
       [ 2, 14]])
```

How do I do that? I would like the result of numpy's "advanced indexing" to be *implicitly* transposed. Transposing it explicitly with `.T` at the end is even slower and is not an option.

**Update1**: in the real world advanced indexing is unavoidable and the subscripts are not guaranteed to be the same.

```
>>> x = [0, 0, 1]
>>> y = [0, 1, 1]
>>> X[x, y, :]
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

**Update2**: To clarify that this is not an [XY problem,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here is the actual problem:

I have a large matrix `X` which contains elements `x` coming from some probability distribution. The probability distribution of the element depends on the neighbourhood of the element. This distribution is unknown so I follow the [Gibbs sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling) procedure to build a matrix which has elements from this distribution. In a nutshell it means that I make some initial guess for matrix `X` and then I keep iterating over the elements of matrix `X` updating each element `x` with a formula that depends on the neighbouring values of `x`. So, for any element of a matrix I need to get its neighbours (advanced indexing) and perform some operation on them (summation in my example). I have used `line_profiler` to see that the line which takes most of the time in my code is taking the sum of an array with respect to dimension `0` rather than `-1`. Hence I would like to know if there is a way to produce an already-transposed matrix as a result of advanced indexing.

Comment: i may be surprise if there was a fastest way than `numpy.transpose` to do this job , as it compile in C .!

Comment: I've upvoted your question, but I suspect there might be a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here.

Comment: @NPE I can describe the problem then. Will be updating now

Comment: @NPE did my best to update. The big picture doesn't really help, sry.

Comment: @all3fox: This is great, thanks for taking the time to provide some context.

Comment: I would guess that it is the actual memory layout that matters, not what axis that is.  In other words, if the items you want to sum are not stored adjacent in memory, it will be slow no matter what axis of the resulting matrix they're in.  If you managed to get the transposed matrix, you would just move the slowdown from the sum operation to the transpose operation.

Comment: @BrenBarn yes, you are right, memory layout is what I am after. In python, the last index `-1` in the default `C` memory layout is the fastest (locality). That is why I need the new array, which is always created by advanced indexing, to be transposed --- this way I will be able to sum along the fastest index.

Comment: @all3fox "In python, the last index -1 in the default C memory layout is the fastest (locality)" - no, I think you're getting mixed up with Fortran arrays. With a row-major array it will be faster to address adjacent elements in the *0th* dimension, not the *-1th* dimension.

Comment: @ali_m, that seems exactly backwards. And when I tested it, it was false. `X = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100); X.sum(-1)` is fastest for me (by a factor of .6:1); `X.sum(1)` is just a bit faster than `X.sum(0)` (by a factor of about .9:1). See my comment below.

Comment: @senderle That's weird - using the exact same setup, `X.sum(0)` takes 819us, `X.sum(1)` takes 861us and `X.sum(2)` takes 887us. In your example can you confirm that `X.flags.c_contiguous == True`?

Comment: Confirmed. `X.flags.c_contiguous` is `True`. Edited: re-confirmed after your comment below.

Comment: @senderle In which case my only thought is that this must be some weird architecture-dependent thing. Do you have another machine you can test this on?

Comment: It would be almost identical hardware. But the theoretical point remains -- summing over `-1` _ought_ to be fastest, unless I'm disastrously mistaken. But I guess all bets are off it it depends on architecture or `numpy` version. I'm using an Intel Mac with built-in `numpy` version 1.6.2.

Comment: @senderle FWIW this really does seem to be numpy version-related - I also see that the order of the timings is reversed for numpy v1.6.2. I must admit that I've never thought very hard about what the theoretically optimal ordering should be - I always just go with whatever benchmarks fastest. Based on my reading of the wiki page, it does seem like summing over the last dimension ought to be the most cache-friendly, but the fact is that (at least for recent versions of numpy), the opposite seems to be true.

Comment: Interesting! Well that proves your larger point, doesn't it? Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67812/discussion-between-senderle-and-ali-m).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to sum it along the 0 dimension but in the real world the matrix is huge and I would prefer to be summing it along -1 dimension which is faster due to memory layout.

I'm not totally sure what you mean by this. If the underlying array is row-major (the default, i.e. `X.flags.c_contiguous == True`), then it may be *slightly* faster to sum it along the *0th* dimension. Simply transposing an array using `.T` or `np.transpose()` does not, in itself, change how the array is laid out in memory.

For example:

```
# X is row-major
print(X.flags.c_contiguous)
# True

# Y is just a transposed view of X
Y = X.T

# the indices of the elements in Y are transposed, but their layout in memory
# is the same as in X, therefore Y is column-major rather than row-major
print(Y.flags.c_contiguous)
# False
```

You can convert from row-major to column-major, for example by using `np.asfortranarray(X)`, but there is no way to perform this conversion without making a full copy of `X` in memory. Unless you're going to be performing lots of operations over the columns of `X` then it almost certainly won't be worthwhile doing the conversion.

If you want to store the *result* of your summation in a column-major array, you could use the `out=` kwarg to `X.sum()`, e.g.:

```
result = np.empty((3, 3), order='F') # Fortran-order, i.e. column-major
X.sum(0, out=result)
```

In your case the difference between summing over rows vs columns is likely to be *very* minimal, though - since you are already going to be indexing non-adjacent elements in `X` you will already be losing the benefit of [spatial locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Spatial_and_temporal_locality_usage) that would normally make summing over rows slightly faster.

For example:

```
X = np.random.randn(100, 100, 100)

# summing over whole rows is slightly faster than summing over whole columns
%timeit X.sum(0)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 438 µs per loop
%timeit X.T.sum(0)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 486 µs per loop

# however, the locality advantage disappears when you are addressing
# non-adjacent elements using fancy indexing
%timeit X[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], :].sum()
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.72 µs per loop
%timeit X.T[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], :].sum()
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.63 µs per loop
```

### Update

**@senderle** has mentioned in the comments that using numpy v1.6.2 he sees the opposite order for the timing, i.e. `X.sum(-1)` is faster than `X.sum(0)` for a row-major array. This seems to be related to the version of numpy he is using - using v1.6.2 I can reproduce the order that he observes, but using two newer versions (v1.8.2 and 1.10.0.dev-8bcb756) I observe the opposite (i.e. `X.sum(0)` is faster than `X.sum(-1)` by a small margin). Either way, I don't think it's likely that changing the memory order of the array is likely to help much for the OP's case.

Comment: To clarify what I want: I know that advanced indexing makes a new numpy array. I would like it to make a transposed version of this array instead.

I also see your timings, thank you. Looks like the speedup will be small after all.

Comment: In my timings with your 3d `X`, `X.sum(0)` and `X.T.sum(-1)` take the same time.  `X.sum(-1)` and `X.T.sum(0)` are equally faster.  `X.T` just changes the array to `Fcontiguous`.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not surprised to see variability in the magnitude of the effect - these locality effects are usually very CPU- and compiler-dependent

Comment: I feel there may be some confusion about what "summing along the x dimension" means. As I understand it, `a.sum(0)` "sums along the 0th dimension," meaning that it sums _column_ vectors. In other words, it _reduces_ the 0th dimension. So if you have a `(2, 5)` array, and you sum over the 0 dimension, you get a five-item array. Since `numpy` by default stores data contiguously by row, summing over the 0th dimension will be a bit slower (assuming the dimensions are of equal size).

Comment: And I'll add that when I cut and paste the test code above into ipython, I get the opposite result. `X.T.sum(0)` is _more than twice as fast_. So something's wrong here...

Comment: @senderle I don't know what to say - I've confirmed the timings on two different machines, and with two different versions of numpy (v1.8.2 and 1.10.0.dev-8bcb756). In every case I've tried so far, `X.sum(0)` < `X.sum(1)` < `X.sum(2)`. Can you definitely confirm that `X.flags.c_contiguous == True`?